# Why is sudo apt update failing?

Tags: apt, updates

any help/explanation is appreciated (i know this is such a newb question but nonetheless)

when I try to "sudo apt update" the command fails on one "link" (Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
)

why is that? did the apt update command complete successfully? does this have anything to do with updating repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Thank you in advance for any help folks, greatly appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) As noted by @Olorin, the project is down, probably forever. You should remove the repository link from your system.

Comment: i would love to comment that entry out of the /etc/apt/sources.list, i dont know which one it is, how can i tell ??

Comment: The one containing the hostname `archive.getdeb.net`, just like the error message. However, it might not reside directly in `sources.list`, there is also `sources.list.d`. Search for it using `grep archive\.getdeb\.net -R /etc/apt`.